# Why is Umbra's damage 10 instead of 28?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I just reached level 20 as a sneaky destruction dark Elf and immediately decided to head to Clavicus Vile's shrine to obtain Umbra. From several sources I gather that Umbra's base damage is supposed to be 28, yet after getting the sword it only shows an attack damage of a measly 10 instead of the expected 28. This effectively makes it less than half as powerful as my other blade.

What could be causing this and what, if anything, can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

This is because your one handed skill is low.

from [uesp](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Weapons#Damage_Calculations):

> This modified value is the amount of damage you will see listed for a given weapon in your inventory.

So yes the base damage is 28 but due to your skill you will only do 10 damage.

Answer (score 2):

If 28 is the base damage, other factors may affect it. These include:

- Your one handed skill,
- Your strength,
- The condition of the weapon

If the weapon is in low condition, or your one handed skill or strength is low, you will not do as much damage with the weapon.

To increase your damage. Repair the item to full condition, upgrade your one handed skill and your strength.

Comment: The condition? I was under the impression that Skyrim had done away with durability and item repair.

Comment: This question is tagged oblivion, not skyrim.

Answer (score -3):

You seem to be poisoned or diseased. To remedy, either find a cure or get blessings from a shrine.